# Error en consulta select a dentro de foreach

Tags: php, mysql

mira os cuento tengo un código que realiza una consulta foreach para luego insertar en otra tabla varios datos de cada registro devuelto limitandolo a 3.
Ahí se juntan con otros datos de un formulario y se inserta en otra tabla.

El problema esta que dentro del foreach seria necesario hacer otra consulta para consultar otro dato según el id de los resultados del foreach. pero no devuelve ningún dato esa consulta.

He revisado i existe todo en base de datos. Simplemente no devuelve ningún dato de esa consulta. La devuelve vacía y no debería ser así

Os dejo la parte del código. he marcado en comentarios la parte en la que no esta devolviendo ninguna consulta y no se que puede ser porque todo existe ni sale ningún error en bd.

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users  WHERE Activo=1 ".$subcategoria." order by IdUsuario desc LIMIT 3";
$Prousers = $bd->DB_getDataTable($sql);

foreach ($Prousers as $pro){

  $ProId=$pro['IdUsuario'];

  //Aqui es donde no funciona solo esta parte
  $sql="SELECT * FROM pro_service  WHERE id_user=".$ProId." LIMIT 1";
  $Prosice=$bd->DB_getDataTable($sql);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO price_quote(titulo, precio)
    VALUES ('".$pro['IdUsuario']."','".$Prosice['id_user']."')";
    $reste = $bd->query($sql);

    header("location: job-price-quote?token=$hashed&id=$lastID");


}
```

Comment: Estos problemas es mejor resolverlos por partes para identificar donde esta el problema, corre el programa y primero manda a pantalla el query que generas y tienes comentado como Aquí es donde no funciona, para ver que genera la consulta, si el query esta bien entonces manda el otro a pantalla, y así puedes auditar que es lo que va apareciendo. Tambien esos query que genera copialos y correlos tu directamente en MySQL para ver que regresa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agregando un [0] me ha resuelto el problema.

```html
$Prosice[0]['id_user']
```